# How to retrieve error messages when using Mongoid's #valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid

This is a short and simple question. I'm validating some **Mongoid** documents in memory (without persisting them) using **Mongoid**'s *#valid?* method.

I want to retrieve the error messages when the validation is unsuccessful. How can I retrieve them?, because the *@target.errors.full_messages* is throwing an empty array.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CLOSED QUESTION**

The *@target.errors.full_messages* indeed contains the error messages. It was me making a mistake.

Best,